# Remove rows of dataframe of conditions by another columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, tidyr

I trying to filter values over columns accordingly to some conditions.

I have the following part of my data:

```
df <- tibble(
  v1 = c(5, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7),
  v2 = c(1, 1, 1, 5, 20, 30, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7),
  v3 = factor(c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"))
)
```

I trying to remove rows of `df` associated with factor `a` of a variable v3 that are lower to min and higher do max values of factor `b` in v3 to the same variable (v1 and v2).

The expected df I wait is:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
     v1    v2 v3   
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
1     5     1 a    
2     7     1 a    
3     4     1 a    
4     3     1 b    
5     4     4 b    
6     5     5 b    
7     6     6 b    
8     6     6 b    
9     7     7 b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following logical statements are equivalent:

```r
df %>%
  filter(!if_any(v1:v2, ~ .x < min(.x[v3 == 'b']) | .x > max(.x[v3 == 'b'])))
```

```r
df %>%
  filter(if_all(v1:v2, ~ between(.x, min(.x[v3 == 'b']), max(.x[v3 == 'b']))))
```

###### Output

```r
# # A tibble: 9 × 3
#      v1    v2 v3   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
# 1     5     1 a    
# 2     7     1 a    
# 3     4     1 a    
# 4     3     1 b    
# 5     4     4 b    
# 6     5     5 b    
# 7     6     6 b    
# 8     6     6 b    
# 9     7     7 b
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found an answer.

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(v1 >= min(df$v1[v3 == "b"]) & v1 <= max(df$v1[v3 == "b"]),
                v2 >= min(df$v2[v3 == "b"]) & v2 <= max(df$v2[v3 == "b"]))
```

However for not finished this question. How can I put this in a function or a `for(){}` to realize this operation when we have several numeric quantitative variables, not only two.